# How to use bash to get the last day of each month for the current year without using if else or switch or while loop?

Tags: bash, unix

As we know that each year have the following max day in each month as follows:

```
Jan - 31 days
Feb - 28 days / 29 days (leap year)
Mar - 31 days
Apr - 30 days
May - 31 days
Jun - 30 days
Jul - 31 days
Aug - 31 days
Sep - 30 days
Oct - 31 days
Nov - 30 days
Dec - 31 days
```

How to I get bash to return the value (last day of each month) for the current year without using `if else` or `switch` or `while` loop?

Comment: Are you limiting yourself to only bash?

Comment: @jedwards I am open to other bash but must be in unix / linux

Comment: Why the restrictions? Is thia homework?

Comment: @KeithThompson Nope, this is not a homework. I am more interested in optimize speed and using lesser command to accomplish tasks and was wondering if bash can get the last day of a month without telling bash to go through a loop (e.g. if a certain month value, then display this value) or performing hard-coding.

Comment: If speed optimization is your concern, then I suggest saying so rather than imposing specific restrictions. If speed is that important, a C program would probably be a better choice.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

my take:

```
for m in {1..12}; do
  date -d "$m/1 + 1 month - 1 day" "+%b - %d days"; 
done
```

To explain: for the first iteration when m=1 the `-d` argument is "1/1 + 1 month - 1 day" and "1/1" is interpreted as Jan 1st. So Jan 1 + 1 month - 1 day is Jan 31. Next iteration "2/1" is Feb 1st, add a month subtract a day to get Feb 28 or 29. And so on.

Comment: Very nice, only one call to date, beats mine!

Comment: @amdn: this may be better code, but without your explanation (below), I'd have no clue what this is doing :-)

Comment: Note that the date description string can be reduced from "$m/1 + 1 month - 1 day" to "$m/1 month day ago".

Comment: ... at the cost of comprehension.

Comment: ah, yes, comprehension: I first thought $m/1 was a division, but it's actually the base date for the calculation. I added the year, so it's more flexible and maybe less confusing: 
`y=2000; m=2; date --date="$y/$m/1 + 1 month - 1 day" "+%b %Y - %d days";`

Comment: Like several of the other answers here, this requires GNU `date`, which is generally not the version installed on non-Linux systems.

Answer (score 20):

```
cat <<EOF
Jan - 31 days
Feb - `date -d "yesterday 3/1" +"%d"` days
Mar - 31 days
Apr - 30 days
May - 31 days
Jun - 30 days
Jul - 31 days
Aug - 31 days
Sep - 30 days
Oct - 31 days
Nov - 30 days
Dec - 31 days
EOF
```

Comment: I want to upvote you and downvote you at the same time ;) *(I settled on the upvote)*

Answer (score 8):

```
cal $(date +"%m %Y") |
awk 'NF {DAYS = $NF}; END {print DAYS}'
```

This uses the standard [`cal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cal.1.html) utility to display the specified month, then runs a simple Awk script to pull out just the last day's number.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: The Awk script could be simplified to just `'END { print $NF }'`

Comment: I would like to use this, but the last line is always empty, so $NF gives no output.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you allow "for", then the following in bash

```
for m in {1..12}; do
    echo $(date -d $m/1/1 +%b) - $(date -d "$(($m%12+1))/1 - 1 days" +%d) days
done
```

produces this

```
 Jan - 31 days
 Feb - 29 days
 Mar - 31 days
 Apr - 30 days
 May - 31 days
 Jun - 30 days
 Jul - 31 days
 Aug - 31 days
 Sep - 30 days
 Oct - 31 days
 Nov - 30 days
 Dec - 31 days
```

Note: I removed the need for `cal`

For those that enjoy trivia:

```
Number months from 1 to 12 and look at the binary representation in four
bits {b3,b2,b1,b0}.  A month has 31 days if and only if b3 differs from b0.
All other months have 30 days except for February.
```

So with the exception of February this works:

```
for m in {1..12}; do
    echo $(date -d $m/1/1 +%b) - $((30+($m>>3^$m&1))) days
done
```

Result:

```
Jan - 31 days
Feb - 30 days (wrong)
Mar - 31 days
Apr - 30 days
May - 31 days
Jun - 30 days
Jul - 31 days
Aug - 31 days
Sep - 30 days
Oct - 31 days
Nov - 30 days
Dec - 31 days
```

Comment: I'm running Linux, "which cal" responds /usr/bin/cal

Comment: I know why, cal was not installed in my machine.

Comment: I modified my answer so it doesn't need `cal`.  Still not as straightforward as clyfish's answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Returns the number of days in the month compensating for February changes in leap years without looping, using an if statement or forking to a binary.

This code tests date to see if Feb 29th of the requested year is valid, if so then it updates the second character in the day offset string.  The month argument selects the respective substring and adds the month difference to 28.

```
function daysin()
{
   s=303232332323                                        # normal year
   ((!($2%4)&&($2%100||!($2%400)))) && s=313232332323      # leap year
   echo $[ ${s:$[$1-1]:1} + 28 ]
}

daysin $1 $2                                               #daysin [1-12] [YYYY]
```

Comment: With code also add some details how this answer help OP or other to fix current issue.

Comment: Note: your comments `# leap year` and `# normal` need to be swapped to be associated with the correct line. `s="303232332323"` is the *normal* month encoding for the addition in the `echo` line.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this code

```
date -d "-$(date +%d) days  month" +%Y-%m-%d
```

Comment: The inner `date +%d` call returns the current day of this month.  The value for the `-d` flag becomes (for example): "-8 days month", which, according to the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#Relative-items-in-date-strings) means "subtract 8 days from the current date and add one month".  Subtracting the current number of days takes you back to the end of the previous month, and adding one month takes you to the end of the current month.

GNU `date` also has a `--debug` switch which can help to explain what's happening.

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac which features [BSD date](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) you can just do:

```
for i in {2..12}; do date -v1d -v"$i"m -v-1d "+%d"; done
```

**Quick Explanation**

`-v` stands for *adjust*. We are adjusting the date to:

`-v1d` stands for first day of the month

`-v"$i"m` defined the month e.g. (`-v2m` for Feb)

`-v-1d` minus one day (so we're getting the last day of the previous month)

`"+%d"` print the day of the month

```
for i in {2..12}; do date -v1d -v"$i"m -v-1d "+%d"; done
31
28
31
30
31
30
31
31
30
31
30
```

You can add year of course. See examples in the manpage (link above).

Comment: Nice solution but it doesn't show December does it?

Comment: Good catch. No it does not :-)

Answer (score 1):

Contents of `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
begin="-$(date +'%-m') + 2"
end="10+$begin"

for ((i=$begin; i<=$end; i++)); do
    echo $(date -d "$i month -$(date +%d) days" | awk '{ printf "%s - %s days", $2, $3 }')
done
```

Results:

```
Jan - 31 days
Feb - 29 days
Mar - 31 days
Apr - 30 days
May - 31 days
Jun - 30 days
Jul - 31 days
Aug - 31 days
Sep - 30 days
Oct - 31 days
Nov - 30 days
```

Comment: @Jack: Thanks, yes `end="10+$begin"` should actually be `end="11+$begin"`. Glad you chose Glenn's answer, it is far superior.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [patm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381501/how-to-use-bash-to-get-the-last-day-of-each-month-for-the-current-year-without-u/45125967#45125967) using BSD `date` for macOS (patm's answer left out December):

```
for i in {1..12}; do date -v1m -v1d -v+"$i"m -v-1d "+%b - %d days"; done
```

###### Explanation:

`-v`, when using BSD `date`, means adjust date to:

`-v1m` means go to first month (January of current year).

`-v1d` means go to first day (so now we are in January 1).

`-v+"$i"m` means go to next month.

`-v-1d` means subtract one day. This gets the last day of the previous month.

`"+%b - %d days"` is whatever format you want the output to be in.

This will output all the months of the current year and the number of days in each month. The output below is for the as-of-now current year 2022:

```
Jan - 31 days
Feb - 28 days
Mar - 31 days
Apr - 30 days
May - 31 days
Jun - 30 days
Jul - 31 days
Aug - 31 days
Sep - 30 days
Oct - 31 days
Nov - 30 days
Dec - 31 days
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for m in $(seq 1 12); do cal  $(date +"$m %Y") | grep -v "^$" |tail -1|grep -o "..$"; done
```

- iterate from 1 to 12 (for...)
- print calendar table for each month (cal...)
- remove empty lines from output (grep -v...)
- print last number in the table (tail...)

There is no sense, to avoid using cal, because it is required by POSIX, so should be there

Answer (score 0):

A variation for the accepted answer to show the use of "yesterday"

```
$ for m in {1..12}; do date -d "yesterday $m/1 + 1 month" "+%b - %d days"; done
Jan - 31 days
Feb - 28 days
Mar - 31 days
Apr - 30 days
May - 31 days
Jun - 30 days
Jul - 31 days
Aug - 31 days
Sep - 30 days
Oct - 31 days
Nov - 30 days
Dec - 31 days
```

How it works?

Show the date of yesterday for the date "month/1" after adding 1 month

Answer (score 0):

I needed this few times, so when in PHP comes with easy in bash is not,
so I used this till throw me error "invalid arithemtic operator"
and even with warrings in spellcheck ( "mt" stands for month, "yr" for year )

```
last=$(echo $(cal ${mt} ${yr}) | awk '{print $NF}')
```

so this works fine...

```
### get last day of month
#
# implement from PHP
# src: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php
#
if [ $mt -eq 2 ];then
    if [[ $(bc <<< "${yr} % 4") -gt 0 ]];then
        last=28
    else
        if [[ $(bc <<< "${yr} % 100") -gt 0 ]];then
            last=29
        else
            [[ $(bc <<< "${yr} % 400") -gt 0 ]] && last=28 || last=29
        fi
    fi
else
    [[ $(bc <<< "(${mt}-1) % 7 % 2") -gt 0 ]] && last=30 || last=31
fi
```