# Passing proper month start and end days to parallel

Tags: bash, shell, date, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I want to use GNU parallel to run a bunch of commands like this:

```
python MyScript.py 20131101 20131130
python MyScript.py 20131201 20131231
python MyScript.py 20140101 20140131
(etc)
```

So this question ([How to use bash to get the last day of each month for the current year without using if else or switch or while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381501/how-to-use-bash-to-get-the-last-day-of-each-month-for-the-current-year-without-u)) shows how to get the last day of each month using bash.

I'm not clear though on how to pass multiple arguments to parallel from what I assume will be a repeated running of a shell script to generate the start/end days.

Is there a way to do this easily from the command line, or should I generate all the dates first and put them into a file for parallel to read, or is there a better way?

Comment: What are the first and last dates which should be generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
myfunc() {
     MyScript.py $1 $(date -d "$1 + 1 month - 1 day" "+%Y%m%d")
}
export -f myfunc
parallel myfunc ::: 2013{01..12}01
```